# Windows Explorer Preview .msg

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Does anyone know how to get Windows Explorer on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit to preview Outlook email (.msg) files with Windows Explorer just like it does on WIndows 7: http://www.msoutlook.info/question/417

It previews Word, Excel and PDF files just not Emails????

We are using Outlook 2007.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to accept some of the answers to your previous question before asking new ones

Comment: have you tried to reinstall the app ?

Answer (score -1):

It is possibly related to your version of Outlook.
Try installing the 32 bit version instead of the 64 bit, as stated in the answer here (at the bottom of the linked answer page).
It is described as a work around more than an answer but it worked.

[Read this linked answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/d4370b39-db9c-4e36-a9be-4330a079c285/email-msg-files)

I hope this helps

Comment: Link only answers are usually removed. Can you add the solution to your post directly? Thanks.